# Why is the middleware named in the below example

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I was reading the documentation on router in express from the following link
 [http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) { //why is the middle ware named here
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

I have a doubt (check the comment in the code ) that why in router.use(.....) the middle ware is named ie. its named timeLog whereas generally we don't write an name in middlewares we directly write function(req,res)..I am a beginner in this field so I might be asking something obvious..but anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: The name `timeLog` is not actually used, it is probably just for readability

Comment: It doesn't matter if you remove that name. It's just for readability purpose and justifying what this function is actually doing.

Comment: Ok...haven't seen this kind of thing  anywhere else anyways